# conditionally append value to list of lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to conditionally append a list of lists in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3]})
df['B'] = [[[1],[1],[1]]] * df.shape[0] 
df

       A                B
    0  1  [[1], [1], [1]]
    1  2  [[1], [1], [1]]
    2  3  [[1], [1], [1]]

# attempting to append 1st list of lists in B column with 2
df['B'] = df['B'].mask(df.A == 2, df['B'].apply(lambda x: x[0].append(2)))
df
       A                         B
    0  1  [[1, 2, 2, 2], [1], [1]]
    1  2                      None
    2  3  [[1, 2, 2, 2], [1], [1]]

#expected result I'm hoping for is: 
df['B'] = [[[1],[1],[1]],[[1,2],[1],[1]],[[1],[1],[1]]]
df

       A                   B
    0  1     [[1], [1], [1]]
    1  2  [[1, 2], [1], [1]]
    2  3     [[1], [1], [1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.append` works in place, so it actually returns `None` instead of a list. This is why your new df has `None` on the second row.

Below is a way to add 2 to the list. We take the first list in the second row and add `[2]`, then unpack the rest of the lists to form the expected output:

```
df['B'].mask(df['A'].eq(2),lambda x: x.map(lambda x: [x[0] + [2],*x[1:]]))
```

Output:

```
0       [[1], [1], [1]]
1    [[1, 2], [1], [1]]
2       [[1], [1], [1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

try using a lambda function to conditionally modify the list of lists like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3]})
df['B'] = [[[1],[1],[1]]] * df.shape[0] 

df['B'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['B'] if row['A'] != 2 else [row['B'][0] + [2]] + row['B'][1:], axis=1)

print(df)
```

here we create a new list of lists that includes the modified list and then return that. `apply` method is called on the entire DataFrame with axis=1 to apply the lambda function row-wise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way how you generate your data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3]})
df['B'] = [[[1],[1],[1]]] * df.shape[0] 
df
```

The `[[[1],[1],[1]]] * df.shape[0]`  is a tricky thing in Python.
Because all `[[1],[1],[1]]` in the different rows of you `df` point to the
same object, a list `[[1], [1], [1]]`.

Try this:

```
df.at[1, 'B'][0] = [1, 2]
```

`.at[ ]` allows you to access using index number and column name at the same time. the `[0]` chooses the first element of the list returned after access.
So no `lambda` needed here.

One thinks that only the first element in the second row's 'B' columns' list
`[[1], [1], [1]]` is changed to `[[1, 2], [1], [1]]`.
but if you look at the entire data frame:

```
df
```

it returns:

```
   A                   B
0  1  [[1, 2], [1], [1]]
1  2  [[1, 2], [1], [1]]
2  3  [[1, 2], [1], [1]]
```

Because the elements in `B` point all to the identical object, they all get mutated at once.

That is why you should avoid `[  ] * <number>` when generating such constructs.

Instead, use e.g. a list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3]})
df['B'] = [[[1],[1],[1]] for _ in range(df.shape[0])] 
df

# and mutate by:
df.at[1, 'B'][0] = [1, 2]

df

   A                   B
0  1     [[1], [1], [1]]
1  2  [[1, 2], [1], [1]]
2  3     [[1], [1], [1]]
```

### Avoid `append` in your lambda

How about:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3]})
df['B'] = [[[1],[1],[1]] for _ in range(df.shape[0])] 
df


import copy

def myfun(x):
    l = copy.deepcopy(x)
    l[0] = l[0] + [2]
    return l
    
df.at[1, 'B'] = myfun(df.at[1, 'B']) 

df

   A                   B
0  1     [[1], [1], [1]]
1  2  [[1, 2], [1], [1]]
2  3     [[1], [1], [1]]
```

One could use `np.where()` to get row index:

```
df.at[np.where(df['A'] == 2)[0][0], 'B'] = myfun(df.at[np.where(df['A'] == 2)[0][0], 'B'])
```

Comment: your explanation of the proper way to construct column 'B' makes a lot of sense.  what about the conditional append rather than by index?  is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Well, you could apply your lambda on the result. The `.mask` is slower than access via index.

Comment: ah I also see now - `append` in your lambda is problematic - because it is mutating the original object. would you just return a new list instead using append, it might have gone well, perhaps. But call-by-reference here in python will create you later problems.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import copy

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3]})
df['B'] = [[[1],[1],[1]]] * df.shape[0] 


i,j = 1,1
l = copy.deepcopy(df.iat[i, j]) # Deepcopy to avoid pointer problem
l[0] = [1,2]
df.iat[i, j] = l

print(df)
```

```
   A                   B
0  1     [[1], [1], [1]]
1  2  [[1, 2], [1], [1]]
2  3     [[1], [1], [1]]
```

Comment: running your code I get `[[1, 2], [1], [1]]` for all 'B' entries (not just for A == 2)